# Run for loop parallel

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm using C#.

I have the following for loop that make some type of brute force (trying all the combines):

```
const int N = 3 * 255 * 300;

for (var i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
                    {
                        //Do something

                    }
                }
            }
```

I want to be able to run this for loop parallel.

What I'm tried:

```
tasks[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 40000; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
                    {
                        //Do Something
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        tasks[1] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            for (var i = 39999; i < 80000; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
                    {
                        //Do Something

                    }
                }
            }
        });

        tasks[2] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            for (var i = 79999; i < 150000; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
                    {
                                                   //Do Something

                    }
                }
            }
        });

        tasks[3] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            for (var i = 149999; i < N; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
                    {
                        //Do Something
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

But It Isn't really help for me, and i dont understand how to do it with `j,k`,
How can I make this for loop to run parallel at the best way?

Thanks!!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to run the code more fast

Comment: This much is clear. But how are you expecting this to work, and how did you arrive at your current parallel code? And what is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help

```
const int N = 3 * 255 * 300;

Parallel.For(0, N, i =>
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
                    {
                        //Do something

                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: This is make to parralel for loop?

Comment: yes, it will. following is from MSDN : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Oh ok, so with this way I dont need to worry about the indexes? this is make the job?